# How to factorize a Linq request with multiple includes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

My model has:

- Several `DeviceStatus` attached to one mandatory `Device`
- Several`Device` attached to one mandatory `Panel`

When I query `DeviceStatus`, I need to have `Device` and `Panel` attached to it in the query result.

... DeviceStatus.Device is null in the query result.

Here is the Linq Query:

```
using (var actiContext = new ActigraphyContext())
{
    var todayStatus =
        from s in actiContext.DeviceStatus.Include(s1 => s1.Device.Panel)
        where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.TimeStamp) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime( DateTimeOffset.Now)
                && s.Device.Panel.Mac == mac
                && (s.Device.Ty == 4 || s.Device.Ty == 9)
        select s;

    // var tempList = todayStatus.toList();

    var todayLastStatus =
        from s in todayStatus.Include(s1 => s1.Device.Panel)
        let lastTimeStamp = todayStatus.Max(s1 => s1.TimeStamp)
        where s.TimeStamp == lastTimeStamp
        select s;

    var requestResult =  todayLastStatus.FirstOrDefault();

    return requestResult;
}
```

If I uncomment the line `// var tempList = todayStatus.toList();`, where tempList is not used, it works: requestResult.Device is set!
But the bad side is todayStatus.toList triggers a request that brings a huge amount of data.

So how to get the DeviceStatus with its relative objects ?

Note: the database behind is SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2):

When you call an Include() over a LINQ query, it performs Eagerly Loading.

**As documented in MSDN:**
Eager loading is the process whereby a query for one type of entity also loads related entities as part of the query. Eager loading is achieved by use of the Include method.
When the entity is read, related data is retrieved along with it. This typically results in a single join query that retrieves all of the data that's needed. You specify eager loading by using the Include method.

So you need to call the .toList() to complete the query execution.

Since the data is huge, you can pickup relative specific columns as per your requirement by using the Select clause.

```
var todayStatus =
    from s in actiContext.DeviceStatus
    .Include(s1 => s1.Device.Panel.Select(d => new 
                                            {
                                              d.DeviceId,
                                              d.DeviceName,
                                              d.PanelID
                                            }))
    where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.TimeStamp) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime( DateTimeOffset.Now)
            && s.Device.Panel.Mac == mac
            && (s.Device.Ty == 4 || s.Device.Ty == 9)
    select s;

var tempList = todayStatus.toList();
```

Comment: I need to return only one element with todayLastStatus.FirstOrDefault(), there are too many todayStatus to execute the todayStatus.toList(), and I need all the properties of the obejcts.

Comment: Not an issue. Instead of calling .toList(), call .FirstOrDefault() on todayStatus. I've updated the Select query. You can retrieve limited number of columns to keep your need in place.

Comment: I don't need the first, I need the one with the lastTimeStamp, that why I Execute let lastTimeStamp = todayStatusForMax.Max(s1 => s1.TimeStamp)

Answer (score 0):

The query doesn't actually run until you do a call like ToList(), which is why uncommenting that line works. If the query is bringing back too much data, then you need to change the query to narrow down the amount of data you're bringing back.

Comment: I already know this: how to get devices and panels attached to the status without running todayStatus request ?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this request is a more simple way to achieve this:

```
        using (var actiContext = new ActigraphyContext())
        {
            var todayLastStatus =
                from s in actiContext.DeviceStatus.Include(s1 => s1.Device.Panel)
                where DbFunctions.TruncateTime(s.TimeStamp) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime( DateTimeOffset.Now)
                      && s.Device.Panel.Mac == mac
                      && (s.Device.Ty == 4 || s.Device.Ty == 9)
                orderby s.TimeStamp descending 
                select s;

            var requestResult = todayLastStatus.Take(1).FirstOrDefault();

            return requestResult;
        }
```

But the question remains: why didn't I get the relative object in my first request ?